# In "Lecture Notes on Cryptography" what does "PTM" mean?

Tags: terminology, security-definition

I came across a handbook named ["Lecture Notes on Cryptography" from Shafi Goldwasser and Mihir Bellare](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/gb.html) and I read their definition 3.1 about poly-time indistinguishability:

> Let $X_n,Y_n$ be probability distributions on $\{0,1\}^n$ (That is, by $t\in X_n$ we mean that $t\in\{0,1\}^n$
>   and it is selected according to the distribution $X_n$).
>
> We say that $\{X_n\}$ is **poly-time indistinguishable** from
>   $\{Y_n\}$ if $\forall \text{PTM } A, \forall \text{polynomial } Q, \exists n_0, \text{s.t. } \forall n>n_0$,
>
> $$\left|\Pr_{t\in X_n}(A(t)=1)-\Pr_{t\in Y_n}(A(t)=1)\right|<\frac1{Q(n)}$$

What I don't understand is what "PTM" means, can you please explain it to me?

Comment: It means Probabilistic Turing Machine, see Section B.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out [by hakoja in the comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60653/in-lecture-notes-on-cryptography-what-does-ptm-mean#comment133250_60653):

> It means Probabilistic Turing Machine, see Section B.2.1.

where the following is written (emphasis mine, this is the full section B.2.1):

> **Let $M$ denote a probabilistic Turing machine (PTM).** $M(x)$ will denote a
>   probability space of the outcome of $M$ during its run on $x$. The
>   statement $z\in M(x)$ indicates that $z$ was output by $M$ when running on
>   input $x$. $\Pr[M(x) = z]$ is the probability of $z$ being the output of $M$ on
>   input $x$ (where the probability is taken over the possible internal
>   coin tosses made by $M$ during its execution). $M(x; y)$ will denote the
>   outcome of $M$ on input $x$ when internal coin tosses are $y$.